# How to exclude META-INFO folder when assembling jar package

Tags: maven, package, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven assembly plugin to assemble a hadoop package with lots of dependencies jars. And in the dependencies there's lots of META-INFO folder which cause errors when I unpacking it. I want to exclude these META-INFO folder, how can I do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go with [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which supports filtering etc. instead of the maven-assembly-plugin which is a little bit limited in that area.